# Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) - no clue where its happening

Tags: user-experience, google-search-console, cls

I have a website that seems to be matching all user metrics when I do run all tests.
But on Google Search Console it's showing a high result on CLS, and I can't find what is the cause of it.
All tools that I do use show me that I have 0 CLS.

I am totally lost and confused about it, as I cannot find the reason of the elevated CLS result.

The webpage I am testing is:

https://www.99contratos.com.br/contrato-locacao-residencial.php

I do appreciate all the help / tips / explanations.

Kind Regards

Comment: It's probably because of page interaction that happens after the initial load. Automated tools won't pick that up, but users might scroll down the page and get layout shifts.

Comment: You do have a point there. When I do click on any action button on my site it opens an animation between screens. I thought that css animation would help me with FID, and actually it did. But it may be the cause of the CLS there. I will remove it and see if the CLS goes down. Thanks!